# Define named range from databodyrange

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define a named range from a table's databodyrange.
I manage to get the address of the databodyrange and can select this range

```
Dim acSh As Worksheet
Dim oLo As ListObject

Sub StelDatabereikIn()
    Set acSh = ActiveSheet
    For Each oLo In acSh.ListObjects
        Application.Goto oLo.Range
        MsgBox "Databodyrange is " & oLo.DataBodyRange.Address
        oLo.DataBodyRange.Select
```

I would like to define a named range based on the databodyrange.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, since it already is a named range, but you can use:

```
oLo.DataBodyRange.Name = "whatever"
```